# how to handle exception where one of the model is having error. Model[9] in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, exception

i have one model in that there are 10 classes. im getting error at Model[9]. how to handle null exception at Model[9].

error
**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

```
 <div class="small-box bg-blue">
                <div class="inner">

                    <h3>  @Model[9].status<sup style="font-size: 20px"></sup></h3>
                    <p>N-7 NEW ST SR @Model[9].deviceid.ToUpper().Substring(11, 5)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i>
                        @if (@Model[9].status.ToUpper() == "CLOSE")
                        {
                            <img src="~/images/door-closed.png"  />

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img src="~/images/door-open.png"  />
                        }
                    </i>
                </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: You don't have a null exception, the problem is that there is no item it index 9, so `Model[9]` is not valid. Where did you get 9 from?

Comment: Also, why do I have the feeling that you have repeated the above code 10 times?

Comment: yes i have repeated the the above code 10 times , because its not a table. there are 10 divs. can u plz tell how to o exception handling so that other 9 divs will give there values. so that page will be rendered